# Batch processing solution for audio files

Tags: editing, audio

I'm looking for a way to batch process large amount of audio files (ogg and wav formats).

Ideally, a solution that works from a Windows' command line, allows conversion between formats, allows applying various effects (e.g. noise removal), delivers basic editing options (join two files together, remove silence from beginning and end of files, append 1s of silence to each file and so on) and it's freeware or open source. It can be a audio files editor with scripting capabilities.

Does anyone happen to know about existence of such solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if i were you, i'd install cygwin. then you can make use of sox and ffmpeg. ffmpeg will do conversion, join files, and sox will remove silence and append silence. actually, if i were you, i'd just install linux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I were me, I'd also install Linux :D But I'm a corporate version of me, so I need to stick to Windows ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/). It comes stock with conversion and extra scripting options, and there are dozens of extensions that are already made for you. In addition, you can script the rest of the program to do whatever you want!

Answer (score 1):

I think Sound Forge accepts VB scripting. Far and Away best in breed noise reduction.

Answer (score 1):

See also [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of features to ask of a free solution! Look into Steinberg Wavelab, which has powerful batch processing, editing, noise removal, etc.  It's not CLI, but for the level of processing you want to do, I'd advise toward a GUI software solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the Vorbis home page I found [this link](http://www.litexmedia.com/audio_wizard/) to a tool which looks like it does what you want.

(I haven't tested it = on my windows machines I pop either a cygwin or a linux VM and do it with ffmpeg and sox)